# How to run Python Script in Nextflow

Tags: python-3.x, workflow, nextflow

I'm new to Nextflow and I tried to run a Python Script in Nextflow. So I stored the Python Script in the same Folder as the Nextflow Pipeline and tried to run it but I always get this error: `.command.sh: line 2: ./example.py: No such file or directory`.
Does anybody encountered the same problem and was capable to solve it?

My Process looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

input_ch = Channel.fromPath('data/*.txt')

process foo {

    input:
    file x from input_ch

    output:
    file "$x" into outputt_ch

    """
    ./example.py ${x}
    """

}
```

P.S.:My Python Script is executable from the Terminal!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nextflow runs each task in a separate working directory. Therefore `./example.py` won't work. You have to use `example.py` and make the script accessible through the system `PATH` or copy it into the project `bin/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the `projectDir` variable.
For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

input_ch = Channel.fromPath('data/*.txt')
project_dir = projectDir

process foo {

    input:
    file x from input_ch

    output:
    file "$x" into outputt_ch

    """
    python $project_dir/example.py ${x}
    """

}
```